# Random Picture From Database MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

Hi trying to grab 7 random photos from my database where type='img'

Some code

```
<?php
$ilosc= 7;
$Query='SELECT * FROM tentego_img WHERE type = 'img' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.$ilosc;
$QueryResult=mysql_query($Query);

while($Kol=mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult)){
echo('<td style="border: 0px"><a href="/img/'.$Kol['id'].'/'.$Kol['title'].'/"><img src="/upload/'.$Kol['src'].'" alt="'.$Kol['title'].'" title="'.$Kol['title'].'" width="120px" height="120px" /></a></td> ');
}
?>
```

So should catch 7 randoms photos where type= img, but have no idea whats wrong with code

when query looks like `

```
$Query='SELECT * FROM tentego_img  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.$ilosc;`
```

works fine but i need to show just photos where type=img

Help Please

Cheers

Comment: well, you have a syntax error in the PHP which kills the script. `'img1'` in your query is terminating the string...

Comment: Use double quote in $Query...

Comment: Try this it will work $Query="SELECT * FROM tentego_img WHERE type = 'img' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$ilosc;

Comment: Please consider using PDO instead of mysql_*; [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and the such are deprecated, and your code is open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different characters:

```
$Query="SELECT * FROM tentego_img " .  
        "WHERE type='img' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$ilosc;
```

or escape the single quotes:

```
$Query='SELECT * FROM tentego_img ' .
        'WHERE type=\'img\' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.$ilosc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must escape your `'` characters or use " around the string

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM tentego_img WHERE type = 'img' ".
         "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$ilosc;
```